# SQL Server 2005 Periodically Cleanup Table Without Causing User Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `Tab_Log` that is filling up with thousands of rows per day. Every week I need to scrub 90% of the rows based on the create date. Using a `delete` statement works but is very resource intensive as all deletes are logged. My second thought was to insert the data I don't want to delete from `Tab_Log` into a temp table, `truncate Tab_Log`, then insert the records from the temp table back in. My concern is that during this process a user could potentially query `Tab_Log` during the truncate and re-insert process and receive and error.

So how can I quickly scrub this table without causing errors to the user? Is there a way to lock the table safely so that any incoming query requests will wait instead of erroring out?

Comment: What *edition* of SQL Server are you on? Enterprise/Standard/Express etc.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Enterprise

Comment: Better to ask this question to dba.stackexchange.com. My answer as a developer with some DBA experience is to use partitioning. See this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/02/14/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-1-the-basics.aspx. The archive section is in the 2nd article

Comment: In that case (as per comment above!) partitioning is available. You can use partitioning on date and easily switch dates out as a quick metadata only operation.

Comment: Do you need to log those deletes?

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski - No, but there is no getting around it as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing your deletes in batches:

```
WHILE 1 = 1 
  BEGIN; 
    DELETE TOP(500) FROM Tab_Log WITH(ROWLOCK) WHERE CreateDate = zyz; 
    IF @@RowCount = 0 BREAK; 
  END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Obvious workarounds.

1 - Schedule the 90% delete for 3AM Sunday using SqlAgent

2 -- Perform the delete without killing the database by deleting the records in smaller chunks.

E.g., populate a temp table with primary keys of all the primary keys of the records to be selected. 
(Doing the prevents having to scan the master table repeatedly, if you are indexed on the date field, just delete top 100)

Sleep for 2 seconds to give other users a chance.

Repeat until nothing left to delete

Tune this algorithm as needed.